# Spring MVC variable resets for no reason

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

For some reason when I execute a GET request to a certain URI the variable that I need to access in that method loses its memory or points to null.

I have a form where a user can update his personal information. But when he enters a duplicate, it redirects him to a page that lets him know

I have : `private static volatile User currentUser;`

This field is set when a user logs in and the server performs a GET request to a REST API, which I programmed myself, and returns the User containing his info. This works as expected and the user info is displayed on his home screen.

Code for the above:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute Credentials credentials,
            RedirectAttributes redirect) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        RoleInfo roleInfo = restTemplate.postForObject(
                "http://localhost:9090/users/login", credentials,
                RoleInfo.class);

        if (roleInfo != null) {
            if (roleInfo.isAdmin()) {
                redirect.addFlashAttribute("credentials", credentials);
                return "redirect:/adminHome";
            } else {
                redirect.addFlashAttribute("credentials", credentials);
                return "redirect:/getBasicUser";
            }
        } else {
            return "login_fail";
        }
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/getBasicUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public <T> String getBasicUser(@ModelAttribute Credentials credentials,
            Model model, RedirectAttributes redirect) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:9090/users/getBasicUser?username="
                + credentials.getUsername();
        ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<T>(createHeaders(credentials.getUsername(),
                        credentials.getPassword())), User.class);
        User user;
        user = responseEntity.getBody();
        currentUser = user;
        System.out.println("current user: " + currentUser.getUsername());
        if (user != null) {
            userName = credentials.getUsername();
            passWord = credentials.getPassword();
            redirect.addFlashAttribute("credentials", credentials);
            redirect.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
            return "redirect:/basicHome";
        } else {
            return "register_fail";
        }
    }
```

So on "basicHome" he can view his information. Also on that page is a link to a form where he can edit the information:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEditProfilePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);
        System.out.println("current use firstname: " + currentUser.getFirstname());
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "edit_profile";
    }
```

If an edit is successful he is returned back to his home page with the updated information.

The problem comes when he enters invalid info. He should be redirected back to the "/edit" URI and the `currentUser`field **should still hold his information but is actually null.**

Here is the "/edit" PUT function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public <T> String editProfile(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
            @ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials,
            RedirectAttributes redirect) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url = "http://localhost:9090/users/update?username=" + userName;

        HttpHeaders headers = createHeaders(userName,
                passWord);

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        HttpEntity<T> entity = new HttpEntity(user, headers);

        ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url,
                HttpMethod.PUT, entity, User.class);

        User returnedUser = responseEntity.getBody();
        currentUser = returnedUser;

        if (returnedUser != null) {
            redirect.addFlashAttribute("user", returnedUser);
            redirect.addFlashAttribute("credentials", credentials);
            return "redirect:/basicHome";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/editFail";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you doing with `static volatile User`! - get rid of the class level variable

Comment: @6ton It's fine. I need it to store a retrieved value instead of playing hot-potato with all the methods carrying around User using model.addAttribute("user", user);

Comment: So what happens when **two** users try to perform the same action at the same time? Looks like your highly unorthodox design is the problem, rather than Spring MVC doing things "for no reason".

Comment: @Kryger, thats why I'm uisng the volatile keyword. I believe it prevents data races and does synchronization but in a different way without using real locks.

Comment: Two concurrent users would still "fight" for the same variable even with volatile, you'd need to use `ThreadLocal` to achieve your goal. Note that it would still be a crappy solution, making it hard to write tests to begin with.

Comment: I figured out what I had to do. I basically made "user" a session object in: @SessionAttributes("user")

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I had to do. I basically made "user" a session object in: @SessionAttributes("user")